# Appengine having issues deploying some current changes to live server Js and Css

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, caching

I have files on my local apengine  site i have new changes especially the javascripts files  and its  work perfectly  locally but after deploying to the live site i discovered that the  javascript file does not have my most recent changes

So far i have been switching fixes by adding and removing cache busting on the file e.g /main.js?4  of which 4 is the active version on appengine

I want to know why i have to do this and what the permanent fix

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know why i have to do this

Check the `expires` response header for these files:

[image]

> and what is the permanent fix

In your `app.yaml` there are a few settings that affect this:

`default_expiration` at the root level

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration

And the `expiration` setting within a static files handler:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element

Comment: i have changed the expiration  value on  app.yaml file but still did not changed the date in the header

Comment: previous files will stay stuck until they expire, did you test this on a new file?